# iOS 7 UITableView selects previous IndexPath after scrolling

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

Ok, so I have this puzzling bug in my app.
I created a TableView dynamically and filled it with some data (the data is not the issue here, empty cells behaves the same). The `UITableView` displays fine and the data is loaded ok. When i tap the rows in the cell everything is FINE, it selects normally and deselects normally! No worries at all.

**Problem:**
When I scroll the `UITableView` it's scrolling normally BUT whenever i try to select a row after scrolling it, the wrong row is selected. The row selected is the one that was pointed at when starting to scroll. It's like the row is getting selected upon touch when you start to scroll and then fires `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` when you try to tap on another row in the table. Once the wrong row is selected you can again select the rows you want, until you scroll again!

**What could be causing this?**

Here's my code for the table view!

```
//Function to display a summary view after answering all the questions
-(IBAction)displaySummaryView {
    viewSummary = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-60)];
    [viewSummary setAlpha:0.0f];
    [viewSummary setHidden:YES];
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.25f]];
    [tableView setDataSource:self];
    [tableView setDelegate:self];
    [tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]; //Taken care of elsewhere
    [viewSummary addSubview:tableView];

    //Get all the answers and sort them right!
    NSMutableString *predicate = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"((SELF.id == '-1')"]; //Init with dummy
    for(Answer *ans in activeSession.answers) {
        [predicate appendFormat:@" OR (SELF.id == %@)", ans.question_id];
    }
    [predicate appendFormat:@")"];
    summaryQuestionsAndAnswers = nil;
    summaryQuestionsAndAnswers = [currentQuestions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicate]];
    predicate = nil;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [summaryQuestionsAndAnswers count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 120.0f;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"formCell%d",indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //Cell creation here
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Indexpath section %d row %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Comment: are you using custom selection in UITableView,you will manage selections in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: @NANNAV what exactly do you mean? That i should handle the selection from within cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: yes,when we use ReusableCellIdentifier,cell will reuse when it appear in tableView,show your select and deselection code.

Comment: Solved it, see below. Tried to manage touches by adding a gesture recogniser in cellForRowAtIndexPath but that only made things worse. Thanks for your effort though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved it!**

I had a window that logged all touches in the app. This is the function that screwed up my code! Good luck any others encountering this bug. It's usually NOT a reuseIdentifier problem.

```
if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
    for (UIView *view in views) {
        if ( ![view isHidden] && [view pointInside:[touch locationInView:view] withEvent:event] ) {
            touchView = view;
            [touchView touchesBegan:[event allTouches] withEvent:event];
            break; //NOTE: this used to be a return in the previous version
        }
    }
}
```